# Trouble with installing libqca2-dev on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, apt, qt

I have installed Qt 4.8.4 from source at `usr/local/Trolltec` and now that I am trying to install `libqca2-dev` on Ubuntu 12.04, the `apt-get` tool fails with a dependency error stating that `libqt4-dev` is required.

How should I introduce my version of Qt to `apt-get`?

Comment: Normally, you can't. This is the devil in the detail when installing things from source. The only sensible solution is to package it so apt-get installs it normally and it functions just as an official package would.

Comment: Use binary packages, not source packages. Backporting is often an option.

Comment: @HalosGhost That is not exactly true. You can use the equivs system (at least in Debian-based systems) to tell `dpkg` that you have something installed that satisfies whatever. A typical use for it is with a local installation of TeX Live.

Comment: @FaheemMitha, yes, I've heard mention of it before. And while it is an option, it doesn't seem terribly clean to me. And since many other distros have no equivalent, it seems better to recommend good practice from the get-go :)

Comment: @HalosGhost Oh, agreed. It isn't a good option. But it *is* an option.

Comment: Then I'll stand by my original comment when I said “the only sensible solution” is to use a package. :P